# how to use index with contains operator

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I Have Create a index as bellow:

```
Create index On :Actor(Name);
```

when I Explain the Query Explain `match (n:Actor) where n.Name contains ('a') return n`;It sais NodeByLabelScan.How can I use index with contains operator?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a fulltext index at all, when there are not so many nodes in your database, the query planner doesn't think it is necessary to use the index because it will not have performance improvement compared to `NodeByLabelScan`.

You can force the index usage however like this :

```
MATCH (n:Actor) WHERE n.name CONTAINS "Tom"
USING INDEX n:Actor(name)
RETURN n
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create **fulltext index** for the desired properties.

Refer to this [link](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/fulltext-search-in-neo4j/)